# HttpSession getting error in Twitter web app by using Twitter4J

Tags: java, twitter

Hi I am building a web apps using Java Spring and JSF. I am stuct in login with twitter feature.

I am using Twitter4J. Below is my code :

index.java::

```
public String getLoginTwitter() throws TwitterException, IOException
{           
    twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer("XXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();

    token = requestToken.getToken();
    tokenSecret = requestToken.getTokenSecret();

    session = (HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("token", token);
    session.setAttribute("tokenSecret", tokenSecret);

    System.out.println("sess"+session.getAttribute("token"));

    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    externalContext.redirect(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL());  

    return null;      
}
```

This code send the user to the login page. Its working fine. I saved the token and token secret in the session. Upto this is fine. Below is the coding of Callback url servlet:

```
public String getTwitterInfo() throws TwitterException
{
    System.out.println("sess1"+session.getAttribute("token"));
    return null;
}
```

When I want to access those token from session, I am getting Nullpointer Exception.

Can anyone tell me the right direction. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. Actually callback url of twitter does not support localhost. Thats why I am using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. For that reason, session giving me a null pointer exception. When I try to run this using localhost from browser, it works fine.